# How to configure the Server name dynamically using linked servers

Tags: sql-server-2008, linked-server

Here are the steps  I have followed:

Step1: I have created the Linked server .

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver
    @server='servername', -- here you can specify the name of the linked server
    @srvproduct='',     
    @provider='sqlncli', -- using SQL Server Native Client
    @datasrc='servername',   -- add here your server name
    @location='',
    @provstr='',
    @catalog='Archive'  -- add here your database name as initial catalog (you  cannot connect to the master database)
```

Step 2: Insert the data from main table to archive table(linked server)

```
Insert INTO [servername].[Archive].[dbo].[Archivetb](ArchiveID, ArchiveIdentifier, Code, Type, DateCreated, DateUpdated, DateArchived)
   Select 
      ArchiveID, ArchiveIdentifier, Code, Type,
      DateCreated, DateUpdated
   From 
      [Main].[dbo].Error
```

Step 3:

Delete the data from the records which are inserted.

Above servername I have hardcoded in  Insert INTO [**servername**]. make it configurable for server names for both source and destination servers.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

create a view from Archivetb in your main server and then insert the data to the view.